# Pandas not able to groupby every field in a csv

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following csv file

```
Hour, L,  Dr, Tag, Code,   Vge
 0,   L5, XI, PS,  4R,     15
 5,   L5, XI, PS,  4R,     12
 2,   L0, St, v2T, 4R,     11
 8,   L2, TI, sst, 4R,     8
 12,  L5, XI, PS,  4R,     18
```

I am using the following python code.The idea is to wrap my head around pandas groupby concept.

```
# !/usr/bin/env python3.4
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd
import pprint

df = pd.read_csv('in.csv')
gb = df.groupby('Hour')
pprint.pprint(list(gb))
```

This is the output that I get.

```
 [(0,
      Hour      L    Dr  Tag  Code   Vge
0      0        L5   XI   PS    4R   15),
 (2,
     Hour       L    Dr   Tag  Code     Vge
2     2         L0   St   v2T    4R     11),
 (5,
     Hour       L    Dr  Tag  Code      Vge
1     5         L5   XI   PS    4R      12),
 (8,
     Hour       L    Dr   Tag  Code      Vge
3     8         L2   TI   sst    4R      8),
 (12,
     Hour       L    Dr   Tag  Code     Vge
4    12         L5   XI   PS    4R      18)]
```

The above output makes sense. However if I do `gb = df.groupby('Vge')` instead of  `gb = df.groupby('Hour')` in the above code, I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Test/python/concepts/pandas/test_pandas.py", line 12, in <module>
    gb = df.groupby('Vge')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3324, in groupby
    sort=sort, group_keys=group_keys, squeeze=squeeze)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 1252, in groupby
    return klass(obj, by, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 416, in __init__
    level=level, sort=sort)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2166, in _get_grouper
    in_axis, name, gpr = True, gpr, obj[gpr]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1914, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1921, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1090, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3102, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 1692, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(_values_from_object(key))
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3979)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 157, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3843)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 668, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12265)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 676, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12216)
KeyError: 'Vge'
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `df.columns` to see the names of your columns. I suspect that your column named 'Vge' isnt actually named 'Vge'.

If so:

```
df.columns = ['Hour', 'L',  'Dr', 'Tag', 'Code',   'Vge']
gb = df.groupby('Vge')
print(gb)
```